# Python Pulp - No duplicate Names

Tags: python, pandas, optimization, pulp

I have built an optimization script for fantasy football. It essentially has to optimize projected points among 6 players where there is 1 captain and 5 FLEX positions. My problem is that whoever the solver is picking as captain, is also getting selected as FLEX. I want to limit it so there are no duplicate player names selected. Everything works other than this, below is the code and CSV file example of what I am using:

`
[image: CSV File that I am Optimizing "Projection"]

```
import pulp
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from itertools import chain
import csv

file_name = 'C:/Users/Michael Arena/Desktop/Football/Showdown/Simulation_Showdown.csv'
raw_data = pd.read_csv(file_name,engine="python",index_col=False, header=0, delimiter=",", quoting = 3)

player_ids = raw_data.index
player_vars = pulp.LpVariable.dicts('player', player_ids, cat='Binary')


prob = pulp.LpProblem("DFS Optimizer", pulp.LpMaximize)

prob += pulp.lpSum([raw_data['Projection'][i]*player_vars[i] for i in player_ids])

##Total Salary upper:
prob += pulp.lpSum([raw_data['Salary'][i]*player_vars[i] for i in player_ids]) <= 50000

##Total Salary lower:
prob += pulp.lpSum([raw_data['Salary'][i]*player_vars[i] for i in player_ids]) >= 10000

##Exactly 6 players:
prob += pulp.lpSum([player_vars[i] for i in player_ids]) == 6

## 5 Flex:
prob += pulp.lpSum([player_vars[i] for i in player_ids if raw_data['Position'][i] == 'FLEX']) >= 5

##1 Captain:
prob += pulp.lpSum([player_vars[i] for i in player_ids if raw_data['Position'][i] == 'CPT']) == 1


pulp.pulpTestAll()

prob.status

prob.solve()


raw_data["is_drafted"] = 0.0
for var in prob.variables():
    # Set is drafted to the value determined by the LP
    raw_data.iloc[int(var.name[7:]),7] = var.varValue # column 11 = is_drafted


my_team = raw_data[raw_data["is_drafted"] != 0]
my_team = my_team[["Name","Position","Team","Salary","Projection", "Opponent"]]

print(my_team.head(10))

print("Total used amount of salary cap: {}".format(my_team["Salary"].sum()))
print("Projected points: {}".format(my_team["Projection"].sum().round(1)))



print(my_team["Projection"].sum().round(1))
```

Comment: You get the CPT selected also as FLEX because both have high "Projection". Assuming you have `N` players organized as you did, then you want `player_vars[i]+player_vars[i+N]<2` so you cannot select the same player as CPT and FLEX

Comment: So ive been trying to figure out how to add that as a constraint.
. 
```#No Repeat Names
for cptid in player_ids:
    if raw_data['Position'][cptid] == 'CPT':
        prob += pulp.lpSum([player_vars[i] for i in player_ids if 
                           raw_data['Name'][i] == raw_data['Name'][cptid]] + 
                           [-1*player_vars[cptid]]) >= 0
```



.I thought this would work but it doesnt. Would you be able to show me how to implement your suggestion through code / adding it as a constraint? Sorry i dont use Pulp much.

Comment: I will try to give you a more elaborated answer as soon as I have a little bit of time, I apologize :) Your constraints should be something like `pulp.lpSum([player_vars[cptid],player_vars[flexid]])<2` where you have chosen `flexid` to match the name of `cptid`

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to break up your data into a dual-index of (name, position) and things will get a **lot** easier.  The other solution here is good, but is very fragile in that it assumes that all the names who could be FLEX are same as CPT and in the same order.

Here is an idea that doesn't require that and will be more flexible if you grow your model.  Note I used `pandas` to pull in data as you did, but you could also gin up a couple lines to read the csv.  Also, You could construct the model using pandas indexing--in this case multi-indexing--but I think basic python indexing is much clearer in this case, so I tossed the key data into 2 dictionaries.

I downsized your model to select from 6 name-position pairs in this .csv:

```
Name,Pos,  Value, Cost
Bob, FLEX,1.5,10
Sam, FLEX,1.4,8
Tom, FLEX,1.6,9
Bert,FLEX,1.5,9
Tom,CPT,1.2,12
Sam,CPT,1.3,11
```

## script

```
import pulp
import pandas as pd

data_file = 'data.csv'

df = pd.read_csv(data_file, index_col=['Name', 'Pos'], skipinitialspace=True)
#print(df)

legal_assignments = df.index   # tuples of (name, pos)
name_set = df.index.unique(0)  # a conveniece

costs = df['Cost'].to_dict()
values = df['Value'].to_dict()

# set up LP
draft = pulp.LpVariable.dicts('selected', legal_assignments, cat='Binary')

prob = pulp.LpProblem('the draft', pulp.LpMaximize)

# obj
prob += pulp.lpSum([draft[n, p]*values[n,p] for (n, p) in legal_assignments])

# salary cap
prob += pulp.lpSum([draft[n, p]*costs[n,p] for (n, p) in legal_assignments]) <= 30

# pick 2 FLEX
prob += pulp.lpSum([draft[n, p] for (n, p) in legal_assignments if p == 'FLEX']) == 2

# pick 1 CPT
prob += pulp.lpSum([draft[n, p] for (n, p) in legal_assignments if p == 'CPT']) == 1

# use each player at most only once
for name in name_set:
    prob += pulp.lpSum([draft[n, p] for (n, p) in legal_assignments if n == name]) <=1

prob.solve()

for idx in draft:
    if draft[idx].varValue:
        print(f'hire {idx[0]} for position {idx[1]}')
```

## output...

```
hire Tom for position FLEX
hire Bert for position FLEX
hire Sam for position CPT
```

Comment: Hi AirSquid, Would you be able to look at my last post and help me with it? Your answer for this problem helped me a lot and ive been confused with the answer I've gotten. Really appreciate if you can take a look for me as your comment was extremely helpful on this post. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I was talking about

```py
import pulp
import numpy as np


#%% DUMMY ARRAY TO SIMULATE YOUR DATA
Nplayers = 7

raw_data = {}

names = [chr(ord('A')+i) for i in range(Nplayers)]*2
raw_data['Position'] = ['FLEX']*Nplayers + ['CPT']*Nplayers
raw_data['Projection'] = np.random.rand(2*Nplayers) * 10
raw_data['Salary'] = (np.random.rand(2*Nplayers)*10000).astype(int)
player_ids = np.arange(2*Nplayers)


#%% YOUR CODE (I commented few stuff)

#player_ids = raw_data.index
player_vars = pulp.LpVariable.dicts('player', player_ids, cat='Binary')

prob = pulp.LpProblem("DFS Optimizer", pulp.LpMaximize)

prob += pulp.lpSum([raw_data['Projection'][i]*player_vars[i] for i in player_ids])

##Total Salary upper:
prob += pulp.lpSum([raw_data['Salary'][i]*player_vars[i] for i in player_ids]) <= 50000
##Total Salary lower:
prob += pulp.lpSum([raw_data['Salary'][i]*player_vars[i] for i in player_ids]) >= 10000
##Exactly 6 players:
prob += pulp.lpSum([player_vars[i] for i in player_ids]) == 6
## 5 Flex:
prob += pulp.lpSum([player_vars[i] for i in player_ids if raw_data['Position'][i] == 'FLEX']) >= 5
##1 Captain:
prob += pulp.lpSum([player_vars[i] for i in player_ids if raw_data['Position'][i] == 'CPT']) == 1



# HERE IS THE IMPORTANT STUFF!!!
# you can create a clever way to match 'flex_indx' with 'cpt_indx' by their names
flex_indx = np.arange(Nplayers)
cpt_indx = np.arange(Nplayers)+Nplayers
for i in range(Nplayers):
    prob += pulp.lpSum([player_vars[cpt_indx[i]],player_vars[flex_indx[i]]])<=1



#pulp.pulpTestAll()
#prob.status
prob.solve()

#%% PLOT RESULT

tot_proj = 0.0
tot_salary = 0.0

print('-'*40)
print('%9s : %s : %4s : %4s : %4s'%('VAR','NAMES','POS','PROJ','SALARY'))
print('-'*40)
for v in prob.variables():
    if v.value()>0:
        num = int(v.name[7:])
        tot_proj += raw_data['Projection'][num]
        tot_salary += raw_data['Salary'][num] 
        print('%9s : %5s : %4s : %4.1f : %6u'%(v.name,names[num],raw_data['Position'][num],raw_data['Projection'][num],raw_data['Salary'][num]))
print('-'*40)
print('TOTAL' + ' '*20 + ': %4.1f : %6u'%(tot_proj,tot_salary))
print('-'*40)
```